# vuex - unknown action type (can't dispatch my action)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I was trying moving my store into separate modules and couldn't figure out how to dispatch my actions. I can access the state values, but not the action.

Bear in mind this project I'm doing exclusively to learn vue, so I'm definitely a beginner here.

src/store/store.js (acts as my index inside the store folder)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

import posts from './modules/posts'
import comments from './modules/comments'

Vue.use(Vuex)
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://someapi.com/'

export default new Vuex.Store({
    name: 'store',
    namespaced: true,
    modules: {
      posts,
      comments
    },
})
```

src/store/modules/posts.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://someapi.com/'

export default new Vuex.Store({
    name: 'posts',
    state: {
        posts: [],
        post: {}
    },
    mutations: {
        retrievePosts(state, posts){
            state.posts = posts
        },
        retrievePost(state, post){
            state.post = post
        },
    },
    actions: {
        retrievePosts (context) {
            axios.get('/blog/post/all')
                .then(response => {
                    var posts = response.data.data
                    context.commit('retrievePosts', posts)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
            },
            retrievePost (context, slug) {
                axios.get('/blog/post/all')
                    .then(response => {
                        var post = response.data.data[1]
                        context.commit('retrievePost', post)
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            },
    }

})
```

src/components/BlogPostList.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="postList">
        <b-container v-for="post in this.$store.state.posts.posts" :key="post.id" class="post">
            <b-row>
                <b-col>
                    <h1><a :href="'post/' + post.slug">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
            <b-row>
                <b-col cols="10">
                    <h4>{{ post.subtitle }}</h4>
                </b-col>
                <b-col>
                    <small>by {{ post.author_id }} </small>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
            <b-row>
                <b-col>
                    <!-- <p v-html="post.body.substring(0, 1000) + '...'"></p> -->
                    <span class="post-text" v-html="post.body"/>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
            <br />
            <b-row>
                <b-col>
                    <dx-button style="float:right"
                        text="read more"
                        @click="buttonClicked" 
                    />
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
            <hr>
        </b-container>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import DxButton from "devextreme-vue/button";

export default  {
    components: {
        DxButton
    },
    name: 'BlogPostList',
    created () {
        this.$store.dispatch('retrievePosts')
    },
    methods: {
        buttonClicked: function() {
            alert("The Button was clicked");
        }
    }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">
.postList {
    h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    .post-text {
        text-align: justify;
    }
}
</style>
```

I've tried the most "recommended" fix I found, which is changing

```
this.$store.dispatch('retrievePosts')
```

to

```
this.$store.dispatch('posts/retrievePosts')
```

but I get the same error on console...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I honestly can't tell what I'm missing here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because you created another Vuex store inside your `posts` module which you've added as module in your main `store.js`.

Try modifying your `posts` module to the following.

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://someapi.com/';

export default {
  name: 'posts',
  state: {
    posts: [],
    post: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    retrievePosts(state, posts) {
      state.posts = posts;
    },
    retrievePost(state, post) {
      state.post = post;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    retrievePosts(context) {
      axios
        .get('/blog/post/all')
        .then((response) => {
          var posts = response.data.data;
          context.commit('retrievePosts', posts);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    retrievePost(context, slug) {
      axios
        .get('/blog/post/all')
        .then((response) => {
          var post = response.data.data[1];
          context.commit('retrievePost', post);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Aaaand that works! I didn't know I had to simply export it. Thanks!

Comment: @Erik You're welcome. I've always worked with one central store importing multiple modules under it and haven't encountered this problem before. That's why I suspected it might be the reason.